# BeautifulSoup 3.1 parser breaks far too easily

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

*I was having trouble parsing some dodgy HTML with BeautifulSoup. Turns out that the HTMLParser used in newer versions is less tolerant than the SGMLParser used previously.*

---

Does BeautifulSoup have some kind of debug mode? I'm trying to figure out how to stop it borking on some nasty HTML I'm loading from a crabby website:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
        <HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        ...
        ...
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

BeautifulSoup gives up after the `<HTTP-EQUIV...>` tag

```
In [1]: print BeautifulSoup(c).prettify()
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
```

The problem is clearly the HTTP-EQUIV tag, which is really a *very* malformed `<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` tag. Evidently, I need to specify this as self-closing, but no matter what I specify I can't fix it:

```
In [2]: print BeautifulSoup(c,selfClosingTags=['http-equiv',
                            'http-equiv="pragma"']).prettify()
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
```

Is there a verbose debug mode in which BeautifulSoup will tell me what it is doing, so I can figure out what it is treating as the tag name in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem must be something else; it works fine for me:

```
In [1]: import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: c = """<HTML>
   ...:     <HEAD>
   ...:         <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
   ...:         <HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
   ...:     </HEAD>
   ...:     <BODY>
   ...:         ...
   ...:         ...
   ...:     </BODY>
   ...: </HTML>
   ...: """

In [3]: print BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(c).prettify()
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title
  </title>
  <http-equiv>
  </http-equiv>
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
        ...
 </body>
</html>


In [4]:
```

This is Python 2.5.2 with BeautifulSoup 3.0.7a — maybe it's different in older/newer versions? This is exactly the kind of soup BeautifulSoup handles so beautifully, so I doubt it's been changed at some point… Is there something else to the structure that you haven't mentioned in the problem?

Comment: I've got Python 2.5.1 and BeautifulSoup 3.1.0.1. The original broken structure was different, but the problem also occurs with the simplified structure in the question. I have just run the code in your example and have the same problem as before, nothing after </title>. Now I'm really confused!

Comment: One possibility is that BeautifulSoup broke something when updating... did you try with the text copied exactly from your question here?

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/CHANGELOG.html BeautifulSoup 3.1 is based on HTMLParser rather than SGMLParser (as the latter is gone in Python 3.0), which *might* be the problem here. That's sad...

Comment: Yes I tried with the exact text in the question, and I've just copied-and-pasted again to be sure.

Sounds like a pain that the parser has changed. Perhaps I should drop a quick regular expression in to zap the borked HTML. It's not like I'm going to come across anything similar elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

[Having problems with Beautiful Soup 3.1.0?](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) recommends to use [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/)'s parser as one of workarounds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from html5lib import HTMLParser, treebuilders

parser = HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("beautifulsoup"))

c = """<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
        <HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        ...
        ...
    </BODY>
</HTML>"""

soup = parser.parse(c)
print soup.prettify()
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <http-equiv="pragma" content="NO-CACHE">
   ...
        ...
  </http-equiv="pragma">
 </body>
</html>
```

The output shows that html5lib hasn't fixed the problem in this case though.

Answer (score 3):

Try [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) (and its html module). Despite its name, it is also for parsing and scraping HTML. It's much, much faster than BeautifulSoup, and it even handles "broken" HTML better than BeautifulSoup. It has a compatibility API for BeautifulSoup too if you don't want to learn the lxml API.

[Ian Blicking agrees](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/).

There's no reason to use BeautifulSoup anymore, unless you're on Google App Engine or something where anything not purely Python isn't allowed.